# Simplify iterating dimensions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am currently working on a function for averaging images in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). But I feel that the following lines could be much simpler, only I don't know how.

```
    centroidImage(:,:,1) = double(centroidImage(:,:,1)) ./ alphaImage;
    centroidImage(:,:,2) = double(centroidImage(:,:,2)) ./ alphaImage;
    centroidImage(:,:,3) = double(centroidImage(:,:,3)) ./ alphaImage;
```

I get an error if I write it as:

```
    centroidImage = double(centroidImage) ./ alphaImage;
```

Because the dimensions don't match (alphaImage is [y x] and centroidImage is [y x 3]). Is there not a simpler, more efficient way to iterate the dimensions of the `centroidImage` variable, without having to explicitly state them all one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` for this:

```
centroidImage = bsxfun(@rdivide,centroidImage,alphaImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `repmat` on alphaImage:

```
centroidImage = double(centroidImage) ./ repmat(alphaImage,[1 1 3]);
```

Comment: Indeed. But unless you don't have to support old Matlab versions, `bsxfun` is quite a bit more convenient, and, IIRC, faster. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Jonas, you are right, to tell the truth I like your answer more, and it was upvoted by me :) Just wanted to tell another option